# Why int.MaxValue - int.MinValue = -1?

Tags: c#

To my understanding, that should give you an overflow error and when I write it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
}
```

it does correctly give me an overflow error.

However:

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine(test());
}

public static Int32 test(int minimum = int.MinValue, int maximum = int.MaxValue)
{
    return maximum - minimum;
}
```

will output -1
Why does it do this? It should throw an error because its clearly an overflow!

Comment: Am I the only person that was taught that 2147483647-(-2147483648) is actually 4294967295?

Comment: yes. 4294967295 is not an int.

Comment: What would you expect 2147483647 - 2147483648 to give you?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff you're math is incorrect.  `int.MinValue` is negative.  Subtracting a negative value is actually addition.

Comment: @ErikPhilips that's true that the constant is negative.  That doesn't make the math I listed incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff then how about it has nothing to do with the question.  This question is `maximum - minimum` or with default values `int.MaxValue - int.MinValue` or `2147483647 - -2147483648`. I realize simply removing one of the modifiers returns -1, but that is because the CLR is coded that way, not because of some natural mathematics.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I don't think that line of reasoning helps OP, or most people for that matter - it requires knowing that `-int.MinValue == int.MinValue` (and finding that logical). It's not that you're wrong, per se, I just don't think it's particularly enlightening.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`int.MaxValue - int.MinValue` = a value which int cannot  hold. Thus, the number wraps around back to -1.

It is like 2147483647-(-2147483648) = 4294967295  which is not an int

[Int32.MinValue Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue.aspx)

> The value of this constant is **-2,147,483,648;** that is, hexadecimal
>   0x80000000.

And [Int32.MaxValue Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

> The value of this constant is **2,147,483,647;** that is, hexadecimal
>   0x7FFFFFFF.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> When integer overflow occurs, what happens depends on the execution
>   context, which can be checked or unchecked. In a checked context, an
>   OverflowException is thrown. In an unchecked context, the most
>   significant bits of the result are discarded and execution continues.
>   Thus, C# gives you the choice of handling or ignoring overflow.

Comment: The edit explains it, I find it surprising that by default the compiler is in an unchecked state.

Comment: @Aelphaeis:- Yes and to add to it The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

Comment: @Aelphaeis I'm surprised as well as I was sure default was checked. But [per MSDN, indeed `/checked-` is the default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx).  That seems like a bad default choice as it allows programming error to be ignored at runtime (and possibly have [security implications?](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/190.html)). I wonder why the C# team made such a choice...

Comment: The C# standard mandates `unchecked` to be the default, but I realize that doesn't really explain anything, that just changes the question to "so why does the C# standard do that". Maybe performance, but who really knows?

Comment: Usually these things are done for performance. This way, the marketing department can display nice graphs showing how C# performs compared to Java with default settings and optimisations enabled. From a programmer's perspective it would absolutely be better to do checked by default, fail with a nice exception when a check goes wrong and *only* when the software has become stable, enable unsafe mode. But keep in mind that for typical numerical benchmarks, checked mode can be quite slow, since it can easily triple the number of integer ops.

Answer (score 15):

This is because of compile-time overflow checking of your code.  The line

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
```

would not actually error at runtime, it would simple write "-1", but due to overflow checking you get the compile error "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode".

To get around the compile-time overflow checking in this case you can do:

```
         unchecked
        {
            Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);                
        }
```

Which will run fine and output "-1"

Comment: Shout out to @Michael highlighting how runtime overflow checking is an option at the compile level.

Comment: To make this answer complete, you could also show the opposite effect - that of putting `checked` around the calculation in the`test` method - to make that one throw the exception, which is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The default project-level setting that controls this is set to "unchecked" by default. You can turn on overflow checking by going to the project properties, Build tab, Advanced button. The popup allows you to turn on overflow checking. The .NET Fiddle tool that you link to seems to perform some additional static analysis that is preventing you from seeing the true out-of-the-box runtime behavior. (The error for your first code snippet above is "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode." You aren't seeing a runtime error.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes even further than overflows.

if i look at this

```
 Int64 max = Int32.MaxValue;
 Console.WriteLine(max.ToString("X16")); // 000000007FFFFFFF
 Int64 min = Int32.MinValue;
 Console.WriteLine(min.ToString("X")); //FFFFFFFF80000000
 Int64 subtract = max - min;
 Console.WriteLine(subtract.ToString("X16")); //00000000FFFFFFFF <- not an overflow since it's a 64 bit number
 Int32 neg = -1
 Console.WriteLine(neg.ToString("X")); //FFFFFFFF
```

Here you see that if you just subtract the hex values) in 2's complement you get the number that's -1 in a 32 bit number. (after trunkating the leading 0's

2's complement arithmetic can be very fun http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement